# Map specific file to ASP.NET in IISExpress

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

Is it possible to map a specific filename and extension to ASP.NET in IISExpress (via web.config)?

I need ASP.NET to handle requests to opensearch.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a handler to map the required path to the MvcHttpHandler:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="OpenSearchHandler" 
       path="opensearch.xml" 
       verb="GET" 
       type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler"/>
</handlers>
```